# Update only field that is provided

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Now I am doing this:

```
         User.findById(data.id, function(err, user){
            if(err) {
                callback(err, null);
            } else {
                user.email = data.email;
                user.name= data.name;
                user.save(function(err, result){
                    if(err){
                        callback(err, null);
                    } else {
                        callback(null, result);
                    }
                })
            }
        });
```

How do I not updating name if the data.name is not provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check values

```
Object.keys(data).forEach(function (el) {
  if (data[el]) { // if value not `undefined`, `0`, `''`, `null`, `false` 
    user[el] = data[el];      
  }  
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility would be to use underscore.js and user the `extend` function, which will only assign properties   to the target object, if they are defined.

```
var obj1 = { name: "Michael", email:"michael@example.com" };
var obj2 = { email: "michael@whatever.com" };
_.extend(obj1, obj2);
```

Result would be:

```
{
  name: "Michael",
  email: "michael@whatever.com"
}
```